# why datatables not applying on gridview?

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net, gridview

I have this gridview in webforms and applying jquery datatable on it but it doesn't work or appear properly.

I have added the jquery and datatables links in script. It's comming in source. that's ok but not applying.

```
                   <asp:GridView ID="dgvEmployees" runat="server" CssClass="">
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="true" SelectText="View" />
                            <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="true" />
                            <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="true" />
                        </Columns>
                    </asp:GridView>
```

Script at the end of page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#ContentPlaceHolder1_dgvEmployees').DataTable();
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

ASP.Net generates unique IDs for server controls. Try this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('<%=dgvEmployees.ClientID%>').DataTable();
});
```